# Change detection of object from one component to another

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Hi I have an object which is being updated from api using observables in one component and I want to capture the changes of same object to another component. Both the components are two tabs. Initially data is being updated on the basis of route.Here is data being updated:

```
@Component({
    template : `<div><input type='text' [(ngModel)]='data.name' /></div>`
})
export class ComponentOne{

    data : any;
    constructor(private dataService : DataService,
        private route : ActivatedRoute,private events : Events){
        this.data = this.route.snapshot.data['data'];
    }
    updateData(){
        this.dataService.update(this.data).subscribe(result => {
            this.data = result;
            this.events.publish('data',this.data);
        })
    }
}
```

And here I am capturing the data :

```
@Component({
    template : `<div>{{data.name}}</div>`
})
export class ComponentTwo{
    data : any;
    constructor(private dataService : DataService,
        private route : ActivatedRoute,private events : Events){
        this.data = this.route.snapshot.data['data'];
    }

    ngViewDidEnter(){
        //why updated data not coming from server
        this.data = this.route.snapshot.data['data'];
        this.events.subscribe('data',(data) => {
            this.data = data;
        })
    }
}
```

In `ComponentTwo` data is being initially getting from route. Considering above scenario, I have two questions  :

1. If application have multiple components ,I think I will have to
   `subscribe` the event in each component, it would be a good
   practice. Please suggest any alternating approach?
2. Why I am not getting the updated data from `this.route.snapshot.data['data']` 
   in `ComponentTwo` as data is coming from server?

Answer (score 0):

Since they aren't related in any way, you should use a sharing service for that.

Start by creating a service, and add a `Subject` to it

```
export class SharingService {
  data: Subject<any> = new Subject();
}
```

In your first component, you will update the data and pass it to the subject

```
updateData(){
    this.dataService.update(this.data).subscribe(result => {
        this.data = result;
        this.sharingService.data.next(data);
        this.events.publish('data',this.data);
    })
}
```

In your second service, you now can subscribe to change events :

```
constructor(
    private dataService : DataService,
    private route : ActivatedRoute,
    private events : Events,
    private sharingService: SharingService
){
    sharingService.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

Not that both of your tabs must be instanciated in order for this to work. If they're not, then you must use a `BehaviorSubject` instead :

```
data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
```

Comment: if I subscribe to `SharingService` inside constructor only, wont it only be called once when component will be instantiated and for subsequent page enter, it wont?

Comment: No, subscriptions are called everytime you call `next` on the subject. This means that everytime you update data, the subscription will be aware of that and will change your data in your second component accordingly

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I've never used events before.

Comment: no. 'Why I am not getting the updated data from `this.route.snapshot.data['data']` in ComponentTwo as data is coming from server?' question is related to `ActivatedRoute`.

Comment: And to share data, you use events :) I've got no idea how events works, that's why I told you I don't know it. In general, I never have used routing data, but from what I've seen, you can't share data with the router, because the data is supposed to be declared in your routes configuration.

Comment: I know `ActivatedRoute` are used to get data on the basis of route. Here I am trying to fetch data from server once the view is loaded by `this.route.snapshot.data['data']`. My question is why this is not being called on `ionViewDidEnter `. Apologies if the question was not clear.

Comment: `ActivatedRoute` is used to get string parameters from the URL. Not for getting data. If you want to make http calls when the view is loaded, use `ngOnInit`. With a sharing service, you won't need route data (or whatever you tried to use) anymore.